# Highlight ListViewItem only OnMouseOver and Modifier key pressed

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to add a style to my ListView's ItemContainerStyle so that the row will only be highlighted in certain color when my mouse move over that row and a modifier key was pressed (say Alt). The MouseOver part is straight forward but not sure how to work on the key pressed part in the Style.

XAML for highlight OnMouseOver:

```
<Style x:Key="CustomListViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border x:Name="ListViewItemBorder" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" />
                    <GridViewRowPresenter Columns="{TemplateBinding GridView.ColumnCollection}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                </Grid>
              <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                  <Setter TargetName="ListViewItemBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                  <Setter TargetName="ListViewItemBorder" Property="BorderThickness" Value="4"/>
                </Trigger>
              </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

My workaround is using a custom `EventTriggerBase<T>` from `System.Windows.Interactivity`.

```
public class MyMouseMoveEvenTrigger : EventTriggerBase<ListView>
{
    public ModifierKeys Modifier
    {
        get { return (ModifierKeys) GetValue(ModifierProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ModifierProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ModifierProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Modifier", typeof (ModifierKeys), typeof (MyMouseMoveEvenTrigger), new PropertyMetadata(ModifierKeys.None));

    public Key Key
    {
        get { return (Key) GetValue(KeyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(KeyProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty KeyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Key", typeof (Key), typeof (MyMouseMoveEvenTrigger), new PropertyMetadata(Key.None));

    private bool _matchPredicate;

    private ListView ListView
    {
        get { return AssociatedObject as ListView; }
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        Keyboard.AddPreviewKeyDownHandler(ListView, PreviewKeyDownHandler);
        Keyboard.AddKeyUpHandler(ListView, KeyUpHandler);

        base.OnAttached();
    }

    private void PreviewKeyDownHandler(object s, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        var modifierOk = Equals(Modifier, DependencyProperty.UnsetValue) || Modifier == ModifierKeys.None || Keyboard.Modifiers == Modifier;
        var keyOk = Equals(Key, DependencyProperty.UnsetValue) || Key == Key.None || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key);

        _matchPredicate = modifierOk && keyOk;
        e.Handled = _matchPredicate;

        RefreshItems();
    }

    private void KeyUpHandler(object s, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        _matchPredicate =
            (Equals(Modifier, DependencyProperty.UnsetValue) || Modifier == ModifierKeys.None)
            &&
            (Equals(Key, DependencyProperty.UnsetValue) || Key == Key.None);

        RefreshItems();
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        Keyboard.RemoveKeyDownHandler(ListView, PreviewKeyDownHandler);
        Keyboard.RemoveKeyUpHandler(ListView, KeyUpHandler);

        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    protected override void OnEvent(EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Keyboard.Focus(ListView);

        var modifierOk = Equals(Modifier, DependencyProperty.UnsetValue) || Modifier == ModifierKeys.None || Keyboard.Modifiers == Modifier;
        var keyOk = Equals(Key, DependencyProperty.UnsetValue) || Key == Key.None || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key);

        _matchPredicate = modifierOk && keyOk;

        RefreshItems();
    }

    private void RefreshItems()
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem lvi in ListView.Items)
        {
            lvi.Tag = _matchPredicate && lvi.IsMouseOver ? "Yes" : null;
        }
    }

    protected override string GetEventName()
    {
        return "MouseMove";
    }
}
```

Because of `MyMouseMoveEvenTrigger` uses the `Tag` property (set the string "Yes" when predicate match) we need to change the `ControlTemplate.Triggers`.

```
...
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="Tag" Value=""/>
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="Yes">
        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="4"/>
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
...
```

And finally, include the custom trigger to the ListView object. The example uses the key **C** and the modifier **Alt**.

```
<ListView>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <wpfCalc:MyMouseMoveEvenTrigger Modifier="Alt" Key="C"/>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
...
</ListView>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I tried you codes and i have two issues, the handler in Keyboard.AddKeyDown/UpHandler was never fired somehow, do you know why? and the highlight is still there when i held the key and dragged my mouse out of the list view

Comment: @MKJackson Test my answer update. The issue you saw I think was keyboard focus, now I  added `Keyboard.Focus(ListView);` to set the keyboard focus to ListView and capture the keys press events. I hope it works better now!